# WCF Service sending DateTime has changing value when timezones differ

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime

I have a WCF service that I call from my client. In one method I ask the server for its details and it returns an object, one property of which is a DateTime field.

I set the current date and time by using DateTime.Now. I checked this on the server and it is correct.

The server is in a different time zone then the client - it is 1 hour ahead.

When I get a response from the service on the client the time is 1 hour different than that on the server.

e.g. server time is 19/10/2018 16:31:33 and the value I see on the client is 19/10/2018 15:31:33.

I can fix this by converting the date and time to a string on the server, sending that to the client and converting that back to a date/time. I'm trying to avoid this though as it will mean changing the signature of the service which will mean re-generating the proxy and rolling out a new client to many thousands of users.

So its something to do with the DateTime format that is used to send the data.

Is there a way to tell the DateTime object to fix the time and not to re-evaluate it at the other end based on the current timezone?

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime to maintain the date's time-zone across machines.

Comment: or you can just use DateTime.UtcNow if it just need to compare time difference

Comment: As is often the case, I found the solution just after I posted the question. DateTime defaults to a Kind of Local. I needed to change it to Unspecified. Like this:             var serverDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

Comment: Just a general tip out of experience: At a former workplace where date/time was really crucial, we worked in UTC, always. Just the "last mile" (i.E. the GUI components) converted to local times.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Fildor. I fully intend to convert the app to UTC.